# Getting error while set radio button value dynamically using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help.I need to set the radio button checked dynamically using JQuery but getting the following syntax error.

**Error:**

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #answer_type"1"[value="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917"]

I am explaining my code below.

```
 for(var i=1;i<get;i++){
      $('#answer_type0[value="' + qdata[i].answer_type + '"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
     $('#answer_type"'+i+'"[value="' + qdata[i].answer_type + '"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
}
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes `"1"`, which is causing the error.

```
for(var i=1;i<get;i++){
      $('#answer_type0[value="' + qdata[i].answer_type + '"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
      $('#answer_type'+i+'[value="' + qdata[i].answer_type + '"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
}
```